# Database Schema for Hierarchical Locations and People in those Locations

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema, hierarchical

I've been looking around for something like this that will fit my needs but I have been unsuccessful. I am looking to create a database that will hold hierarchical locations (i.e. Alpha, Brave, Charlie that will hold (A1, A2) (B1, B2) (C1, C2) and those will each hold individual people that I have in a People table in my database. This table also needs to be changeable (i.e. UPDATE, DELETE). I have looked into this by using parent child relationships but have not been successful in finding how to tie in my People table..

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with foreign keys? Assign each Person an ID and then store that ID in your Locations table.

Comment: Ok, yes thank you, not sure how that idea blew past my mind. What do you think however is the best table layout for all of this?

Comment: I can't say I fully understood your requirements. Is it supposed to track the locations of people?

Comment: A user on my front end website needs to be able to view the Locations and the people inside in a jQuery tree diagram, they should also be able to move these people to a new location. The database locations table needs to hold each person in their selected location and the People table also needs to reflect their location.

Comment: I would also need a table that reflects all the changes of locations for each person, and visa versa(see all people in a location) so yes, it should track where everyone has been.